# User has strange issue when saving changes to an contact in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts

This is my first time posting, so please go easy on me!

I have a user that makes frequent changes and notes to an Outlook 2013 contact in the "People" area. After making the edit and clicking "Save", the change I so clearly made **does not appear until I restart her Outlook 2013 application** for any contact. This does not happen on any other PC to my knowledge (including mine).

Things I have tried:

- Waiting 5 minutes: it took a few seconds on my machine.
- Making the change by right clicking the contact and selecting "edit".
- Clicking the "Send and Recieve All Folders" option.
- Repairing and rebuilding the user's .ost file and Address Book folder under    Appdata\local\Microsoft\Outlook.

None of those attempts resolved this strange issue.

Let me know if I did not provide enough information. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This has been happening since she was given the PC. No changes have been made since she was hired.

Comment: Have you checked her account settings? It's possible Cached Exchange Mode is enabled. While this may not be the culprit, if I recall correctly, Cached mode can delay updates for certain amounts of time. Closing and opening the application would "force" outlook to update any changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will contact the user and report back shortly.

Comment: The user told me that she can try this tomorrow.

Comment: Here is some info on finding Cached Exchange Mode settings: [Click Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-Cached-Exchange-Mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c)

Comment: My apologies for the late response. The helpdesk was slammed for the past couple days. Unfortunately, turning office "Cached Exchange Mode" did not resolve the issue. We waited a reasonable amount of time and it did not display the changes. This was not the case on my PC as it was fairly quick to appear with the mode unchecked.